# Use row reduction to show that A is non-singular if and only if $a \neq 0$ and $c \neq 0$ and $f \neq 0$.

Tags: matrices

Let  $A = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} a & 0 & 0 \\ b & c & 0 \\ d & e & f \end{array} \right]$  where $a , b , c , d , e , f$ are real numbers. (This is called a lower triangular matrix)

Use row reduction to show that A is non-singular if and only if $a \neq 0$ and $c \neq 0$ and $f \neq 0$.

I understand row reduction when using number to in this example eliminate b , d , e by lets say multiplying row one by 2 or 3 then subtracting or adding , but here since its all letters I'm completely lost. Should I add my own values and test a certain case and will that prove it for the general rule ?

Answer (score 1):

[edited]
If $a=0$ the matrix is singular, as there will be row of zeros. If $a \ne 0$ you can proceed with elimination, obtaining the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix} a & 0 & 0\\ 0 & c & 0 \\ 0 & e & f\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now, again, if $c=0$, the matrix would be singular. if $c \ne 0$ you can proceed with elimination, getting to

$$
\begin{bmatrix} a & 0 & 0\\ 0 & c & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & f\end{bmatrix}
$$

Tracking the assumptions made along the way, you easily get the result.

Comment: *"Use row reduction to show that..."*

Comment: You're right, i'll delet the post.

Answer (score 0):

Note: The determinant, by Laplace expansion, is $$a(c\cdot f-e\cdot0)-0(b\cdot f - 0 \cdot d) + 0(b\cdot e - c\cdot d)=acf$$

This is how I solved it:

First, I started with the matrix

```
7 0  0
2 3  0
5 11 13
```

then I filled the zeroes and ones of the row operation matrix:

```
1 0 0
_ 1 0
_ _ 1
```

By experimenting, I filled some of the blanks as:

```
1    0     0
-2/7 1     0
_    -11/3 1
```

Then I solved $7x-11/3\cdot 2+5=0$ Thus, $x=1/3$

```
1    0     0
-2/7 1     0
1/3  -11/3 1
```

Which is:

```
1    0     0
-b/a 1     0
_   -e/c   1
```

Because what $1/3$ is not obvious, I'll calculate it again:

$ax-e/c\cdot b+d=0$

which means

$x=(e/c\cdot b-d)/a$

Hope this helps, but keep in mind that I might have done a calculation error.

Lastly:

If you multiply them, you'll get

`{{1, 0,0}, {-b/a, 1,0 }, {(e/c*b-d)/a, -e/c, 1}} . {{a, 0,0}, {b, c,0 }, {d,e,f}}` (wolfram alpha code)

which is

```
a 0 0
0 c 0
0 0 f
```

Multiply the diagonals, please:)

Comment: How does this answer the actual question being asked, which has to do with performing row-reduction when some of the matrix entries are variables?